# Run HikariCP on netbeans without maven

Tags: javafx, jdbc, netbeans-8, hikaricp

There are lots of tutorials on how to set up hikari with maven but there is proxy 
 in one of networks where i do code. I tried to configure .m2/settings.xml file but without success. I cannot get through that proxy, therefore I cannot use maven.

Is there any way how to implement HikariCp for offline work? Something like I did when I wanted to work with MySQL Database - I have just added JAR files into library and that was it. I tried to find such a jar file for hikari but i have could now find it.

I have also read that Hikari needs slf4j so I have downlaoded it and add slf4j-api and slf4j-simple to libraries like with jdbc connector.

Comment: You don't run 'on netbeans'. NetBeans is an IDE. And if you can't find a Jar for HikariCP, then you aren't searching good enough (if you go to https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP it says _"Or [download from here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.zaxxer.hikaricp)"_, which links you to Maven Central search, which also allows you to download the jar-file. Maven isn't magic: it also downloads Jars and adds them to a project.

Comment: Thank you vey much. This is what I was searching for. Thanks.